# Bash script doesn't see an array created with Awk

Tags: bash, variables, awk, scope, scripting

I want to get a part in every line of a regular file. For this purpose I've used the program awk in my script. I need to put each part in an array.  Something like this works:

```
declare -i j=1
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { a[j]=$6; ((j++)) }' myFile
```

but I have a problem after in the script, when I need to use the array. Indeed the array in the awk block isn't seen by the remaining lines of the script -- the lines outside that block. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Your array ceases to exist after the awk script terminates. The variable `j` inside and outside of the awk script refer to two different things.

Comment: As an aside: While `((j++))` works in `awk` too, there's no reason for enclosing the expression in parentheses (unlike in `bash`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) points out, shell code and `awk` scripts are separate worlds with separate variables that know nothing of each other.
(More generally, any external utility runs in a *child* process and therefore cannot modify the calling shell's environment.)

In order to read `awk` output into a `bash` array, you must read `awk`'s *stdout output*.

In Bash v4+, you can do the following:

```
readarray -t a < <(awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { print $6 }' myFile)
```

This creates Bash array `"${a[@]}"` from the individual lines in `awk`'s stdout output.

Note the use of a [process substitution (`<(...)`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to provide input to `readline` via stdin (`<`), which ensures that the array remains in scope in the rest of the script.

Comment: @Bento: Got it. One additional thing worth noting is that process substitutions aren't POSIX compliant, so they won't work with scripts that target `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash`.